# BCM43228 does not work since kernel 3.15.xx

Tags: wifi, fedora

Since `yum update`, my WiFi is disconnected. The command `rfkill list` returns:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I saw that I have to `rmmod hp-wmi` and I did it and the Soft (seen in the output above) was not blocked after doing this, but the problem remains.

Details:

```
$ uname -a
3.15.10-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 14 15:39:24 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

em1       no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


$ ifconfig 
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 88.177.227.149  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 88.177.227.255
        inet6 fe80::a65d:36ff:fe99:86e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a4:5d:36:99:86:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2307  bytes 1166280 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2666  bytes 364291 (355.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  memory 0xd0400000-d0420000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 88  bytes 6968 (6.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 88  bytes 6968 (6.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3623:87ff:fe49:df30  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:23:87:49:df:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19 


$ lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i network
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 176b
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM943228HM4L 802.11a/b/g/n 2x2 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

NB : 
After booting `ifconfig` returns:

```
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.110.67  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 172.20.127.255
        inet6 fe80::a65d:36ff:fe99:86e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a4:5d:36:99:86:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12485  bytes 3839676 (3.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4671  bytes 974683 (951.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  memory 0xd0400000-d0420000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1504 (1.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 1504 (1.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I need to do `ifconfig wlo1 up`. Whatever it does not work.

the command `dmesg | grep wl` returns:

```
[    7.751232] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    7.801938] systemd-udevd[494]: renamed network interface eth0 to wlo1
[  106.820202] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  106.820208] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Idea #1

I'd start with trying to get the latest Broadcom drivers, which are available here:

- http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

#### Idea #2

Perhaps this blog post is your issue? Titled: [Broadcom Wireless not working on Fedora 20 Kernel 3.15](http://mike-kirk.blogspot.com/2014/07/broadcom-wireless-not-working-on-fedora.html). It details 2 bugs that are detailed here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1307744
- https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=513156

Along with a patch detailed in the Gentoo bug tracker:

```
$ curl https://513156.bugs.gentoo.org/attachment.cgi?id=378836 -o patch.txt
```

The rest of the steps from this blog post are as follows:

*excerpt*

> I took a chance and applied this directly to the code in `/tmp/wifi`.
>   The patch succeeded and the module compiled.
>
> ```
> $ sudo yum install patch
> $ cd /tmp/wifi && patch -p1 < patch.txt
> ```
>
> Next I needed to copy the module to the default modules folder
>   searched by `modprobe`.
>
> ```
> $ sudo mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra/net/wireless
> $ sudo cp wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra/net/wireless
> $ sudo depmod -a
> ```
>
> Next remove any other sofware and drivers that might conflict with
>   this one. In my case this meant removing the Broadcom OpenFWWF package
>   and removing and blacklisting the bcma kernel module.
>
> ```
> $ sudo rmmod bcma
> $ sudo echo "blacklist bcma" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
> $ sudo yum remove b43-openfwwf.noarch
> ```
>
> To install the new module using `modprobe`
>
> ```
> $ sudo modprobe wl
> ```
>
> To load the module on boot I simply ran
>
> ```
> $ sudo echo modprobe wl >> /etc/rc.local
> ```
>
> Finally use NetworkManager to configure the new device.Oh and thanks
>   to my ex-colleague Steve for the laptop ;-)

#### References

- [Fedora Linux 20: Install Broadcom-wl STA BCM43228 Wireless Driver](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-linux-install-broadcom-wl-sta-wireless-driver-for-bcm43228/)

Comment: Ty for help. After doing all steps nothing has changed. Question: Does `/tmp/wifi` already exist?

Comment: Finally it works after configuring: `nmcli radio wifi on`